# How to resolve an internet IP Address into its FQDN

Tags: networking, dns, ip

We are trying to use etherape to see what http traffic is going through our network but, when running, most external nodes are displayed with their IP address and not their fqdn even though etherape is configured with "Name Resolution" on.

I am wondering how I can check in Ubuntu 14.04 whether name resolution from IP to FQDN is working correctly?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ dig +short -x 8.8.8.8
```

[dig](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) -- domain information groper

`+short` -- one line output

`-x` -- reverse lookup

---

If you want reverse resolution of hostnames which do not have public rDNS, you *may* be able to accomplish it by manually adding entries to `/etc/hosts`.  (1) This would be a headache if you have lots of hosts for which you want this to work, and (2) I don't know if `etherape` in particular will observe entries in `/etc/hosts` or not.  But for the example in your comment, you could add

```
91.211.73.234         www.gumtree.com
```

to the end of `/etc/hosts`

Comment: I've run the command which returned `google-public-dns-a.google.com.`. However I then pinged www.gumtree.com but, etherape still shows the pinged node with its IP and not hostname?

Comment: It looks like www.gumtree.com (or marktplaats.nl) does not have its DNS set up correctly.  `dig +short www.gumtree.com` -> `91.211.73.234`.  `dig +short -x 91.211.73.234` returns nothing.  Your system is behaving appropriately (in this instance, at least).  It is marktplaats which has a misconfigured server.  (Note: in all likelihood, even if rDNS was configured, it would not return `www.gumtree.com` for that IP, but rather something like `234-73-211-91-dynamic.marktplaats.nl` or whatever, as it appears gumtree is hosted in someone else's block, and would not be delegated its own IP [r]DNS.

Comment: Hmmm... etherape shows IP address to pretty much 99% of all nodes instead of hostnames though. Maybe problem is elsewhere...